# Javascript: Get the subsets of objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}]
```

I am trying to get the subset of the array objects like below in Javascript:  I also need to add a 10 to value2.

```
var arrayOne = [{date:'01/01/2017',value2:300}, {date:'02/01/2017',value2:330},{date:'03/01/2017',value2:330}]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` to iterate and select

```js
var array = [{date:'01/01/2017',value1:200,value2:300,value3:400}, {date:'02/01/2017',value1:220,value2:330,value3:430},{date:'03/01/2017',value1:250,value2:330,value3:420}]

console.log(array.map(({ date, value2 }) => ({ date, value2: value2 + 10 })))
```

Comment: yes, and I am trying to get value2 and add a 10 to them....

Comment: Please approve the answer if valid

Comment: got it, appreciate your help